# Остаются ли запятые на стыке с тире в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

"До сих пор не могу выяснить, – хотя и не сказать, что сильно пытался, – что же все-таки внушило в мое сознание этот самый образ, который я не застал ни в жизни своей, ни в жизни чьей-либо другой, и который наиболее вероятно проник в мою голову через какое-то (или какие-то) произведение искусства – скорее всего, произведение искусства литературного."

Кажется, если убрать вставку между двумя тире, то получится, что должна будет остаться первая запятая (после "выяснить"), так как она была бы нужна, если бы не было этой вставки...вроде как.

Собственно, в этом и вопрос: убирается ли по правилам первая запятая, или же она поглощается тире?

Склонен считать, что вторая запятая всё же нужна, так как закрывает зависимую часть предложения. (могу ошибаться :( )

В какую сторону копать по данному вопросу?

Мой (наверное странный) подход заключается в том, что я эту вставную конструкцию убираю и смотрю, что бы понадобилось без нее, но что-то немного запутался...

У Розенталя объясняется так: **4) как перед первым, так и перед вторым тире ставится запятая по условиям текста:**

После чего приводится пример:

Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — я менее играл с сестрицей, реже виделся с ней (Акс.) **— запятая перед первым тире закрывает предшествующую придаточную часть, запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастную конструкцию;**

С первой запятой все ясно - она стоит после придаточной части "где обыкновенно и спал", но о какой деепричастной конструкции идет речь?

Если убрать вставную конструкцию вместе с двумя тире, то получим:

Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, я менее играл с сестрицей, реже виделся с ней.

Получается, что вторая запятая попросту исчезает? Немного не понимаю, какую деепричастную конструкцию она должна закрывать ._.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*До сих пор не могу выяснить – х**отя и не сказать, что сильно пытался,** – что же все-таки внушило в мое сознание этот самый образ...*

Ставится только **вторая** запятая, это **перенесенная/структурная**  запятая, сравнить: До сих пор не могу выяснить, ЧТО ЖЕ все-таки внушило в мое сознание этот самый образ...

Вторая запятая **также** зависит и от предложения внутри вставки (что сильно пытался).

**У Розенталя:**

**ПРОВОДЯ почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал**, — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — я менее играл с сестрицей...

Закрыта распространенная **деепричастная конструкция** на основе "проводя". Это тоже перенесенная/структурная  запятая.

**Замечание.**  **ВНУШИТЬ,** -шу, -шишь; внушённый; -шён, -шена, -шено; св. **что (кому)**.  Вероятно, правильное управление: внушила мне, моему сознанию. Или как-то еще.
Например: *что же все-таки **укрепило в моем сознании** этот самый образ...*

Comment: Хорошее замечание - как-то не подyмал даже об этом...
С первым (вроде) понятно, немножеско прояснилось, а вот с примером Розенталя всё еще испытываю трyдности с пониманием, ведь если yбрать вставкy, то остается лишь одна запятая, а вторая исчезает, так ведь выходит?

Comment: > "запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастную конструкцию" 

Но ведь деепричастная констрyкция, если я правильно понимаю, yже закрыта? 

 >"Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью,"

Comment: Говоря yсловно, то в изначальном примере Розенталя всего 5 запятых, а если yбрать вставкy, то их остается 4 - значит, какая-то из них исчезает, но какая? Если сама вставная констрyкция междy двyмя тире не имеет никаких знаков препинания...
Заренее извиняюсь за этот хаос, но вот пока мой yровень восприятия вопроса довольно хаотичен ;[

Comment: Давайте так попробуем: ПРОВОДЯ почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью — там стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — я менее играл с сестрицей...   Здесь первой запятой вообще нет, и видно, что вставка явно относится к первой части, о чем говорит этот несимметричный знак (тире без запятой).  А появляется первая запятая, если в первой части  (до вставки) есть свои обособленные распространители для деепричастия «проводя»,  а это ни много ни мало два придаточных предложения (союзы потому что и где).

Comment: Поэтому первая запятая закрывает именно эти придаточные,  а деепричастный оборот еще не закрыт. При прочтении текста,  как я думаю,  мы все это проговариваем в одну фонетическую фразу  с произносительными паузами, –  а потом (уже после вставки)  делаем выразительную паузу, обозначая структурную запятую, закрывающую деепричастный оборот.

Comment: Посчитаем запятые. Если нет вставки, то 4 запятые, со вставкой 5 запятых. Без вставки после глагола спал стоит запятая, которая совмещает функции: закрывает придаточное места  ГДЕ и закрывает деепричастный оборот. При наличии вставки каждая ф-ия обозначается запятой отдельно, поэтому их пять.